# SQL Optimization - Match Analysis sorting matched pairs

Tags: sql

**Scenario :**
Matching algorithm has identified ID1 AND ID2 have matched.I need to do further analysis on the matching. For that I need to reduce the number of rows in output and sorted correctly.

This input is just sample and subset. Having thousands of actual records makes this task difficult.

**INPUT:**

| ID1 | NAME1 | ID2 | NAME2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | SIM | 333 | SIM |
| 111 | SAM | 222 | SIM |
| 111 | SAM | 333 | SIM |
| 111 | SAM | 444 | SOM |
| 111 | SAM | 555 | SAM |
| 222 | SIM | 444 | SOM |
| 222 | SIM | 555 | SAM |
| 333 | SIM | 444 | SOM |
| 444 | SOM | 555 | SAM |
| 013 | AAA | 014 | BBB |
| 021 | SUB | 111 | SAM |
| 010 | CCC | 011 | DDD |
| 023 | SOB | 333 | SIM |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | SAM |
| 222 | SIM |
| 333 | SIM |
| 444 | SOM |
| 555 | SAM |
| 021 | SUB |
| 023 | SOB |
| 013 | AAA |
| 014 | BBB |
| 010 | CCC |
| 011 | DDD |

I need to ensure that output should have ID should have distinct records of ID1 and ID2 combined which is still fine as I can do distinct and union.

Tricky part is to ensure sorting of data in ouptput. I need to keep the rows that are similar in order.

**Example** :

111,222,333,444,555,021,023 have similar matching ID's in ID1 and ID2 and have to be sorted together. Within this group, the sorting order doesn't matter, just they need to be together. Similarly there could be many such groups.

The rest whenever only 1 pair is there, just need to sort them together like 013,014 and 010,011 and so on

Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. Just tag the one you are **really** using.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something... `SELECT t.ID1 AS ID, t.NAME1 AS Name FROM TheTable t UNION ALL SELECT t.ID2 AS ID, t.NAME2 AS Name FROM TheTable t`

Comment: Actually the issue as mentioned is with sorting. Want data with matching ids in id1 and id2 to be together. A-M,E-F,M-C should be sorted A,M,C together because M has matched and E,F together

Comment: Looks like you want a  [graph components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 0):

For the case of knowing the patterns *a priori*,
`union` + `order by case when` would go here:

```
select * from (
select ID1, NAME1 from tab1 union
select ID2, NAME2 from tab1 ) a
order by case when NAME1 like '%S' then '' else NAME1 end;
```

SQL Fiddle on your data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38131/4)

---

To group based on just ID1 & ID2, added a sorter column,
concatenating the IDs of each row with `least` & `greatest` on [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/381317/18):

```
select * from (
  select concat(least(ID1, ID2), greatest(ID1,ID2)) sorter, ID1, NAME1 from tab1 union
  select concat(least(ID1, ID2), greatest(ID1,ID2)) sorter, ID2, NAME2 from tab1 ) a
 group by ID1
 order by sorter
```

or with `case when` on [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38131/65):

```
select min(sorter) sorter, ID1, NAME1 from (
  select concat(case when ID1<ID2 then ID1 else ID2 end, case when ID1>ID2 then ID1 else ID2 end) sorter, ID1, NAME1 from tab1 union
  select concat(case when ID1<ID2 then ID1 else ID2 end, case when ID1>ID2 then ID1 else ID2 end) sorter, ID2, NAME2 from tab1 ) a
 group by ID1, Name1
 order by min(sorter)
```

Comment: Thanks but the data is just sample, won't necessarily have 'S' in it. With the ID's ID1  & ID2 data should be sorted